# Giant Revolt 1 2022 seatpost replacement

Tags: seatpost, giant

I am looking to get Giant Revolt 1. I saw there is a possibility of replacing seatpost to 30.9.
I saw there is a shim on the front to tighten the seatposst. How does it work when you insert 30.9 seatpost?  Does the same shim stay, if so how does it all fit then?

Comment: Does it normally come with a 31.6mm seatpost?